# Python - Global name not defined when it is

Tags: python, canvas, global-variables, undefined

Hey there I've been stumped by this simple error for the past day and haven't been able to get passed it.
This is the part of the code I'm getting this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1402, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ppppwn3d/workspace/Python/JailBreakBob/JailBreakBob.py", line 110, in buttonclick_mainscreen
    gamescreen()
  File "/home/ppppwn3d/workspace/Python/JailBreakBob/JailBreakBob.py", line 58, in gamescreen
    if pressed == 8 and e1 == answerlistx[randomimage] and e2 == answerlisty[randomimage]:
NameError: global name 'pressed' is not defined
```

Inside

```
def gamescreen():
    imagelist = ["1.gif","2.gif","3.gif","4.gif","5.gif","6.gif","7.gif","8.gif","9.gif","10.gif","11.gif","12.gif","13.gif","14.gif","15.gif","16.gif","17.gif","18.gif","19.gif","20.gif","21.gif","22.gif","23.gif","24.gif","25.gif","26.gif","27.gif","28.gif","29.gif","30.gif","31.gif","32.gif","33.gif","34.gif","35.gif","36.gif","37.gif","38.gif","39.gif","40.gif","41.gif","42.gif","43.gif","44.gif","45.gif","46.gif","47.gif","48.gif","49.gif","50.gif"]
    answerlistx = [-1, -3, 3, 4, -7, 8, 9, 10, -10, 2, -7, 7, -1, -5, -6, -9, -7, 10, -4, 8, 1, -8, -10, -1, -3, -7, -3, 7, 3, -4, 1, -8, -4, 9, -5, -10, 10, 2, 2, -10, 4, 9, -3, 6, 10, -6, 4, 9, -10, -10]
    answerlisty = [3, -6, -5, 3, -2, 4, -4, -3, 4, -6, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, -1, -5, 1, -3, 1, -2, -2, -5, -3, -2, -6, -3, 6, 2, 0, -5, 6, -4, 4, 1, -6, 0, -6, 5, 2, 4, -4, -2, 0, -3, -6, -4, 1, -3, 1]

    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", buttonclick_gamescreen)
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    photo = PhotoImage(file="gamescreen.gif")
    canvas.create_image(1, 1, image = photo, anchor = NW)
    e1 = Entry(canvas, width = 11)
    e2 = Entry(canvas, width = 11)
    canvas.create_window(390, 501, window=e1, anchor = NW)
    canvas.create_window(551, 501, window=e2, anchor = NW)
    canvas.after(1, countdowntimer)
    while cdtimer != 0:
        randomimage = random.randrange(0,49+1)
        game = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[randomimage])
        images = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = game, anchor = NW)
        if pressed == 8 and e1 == answerlistx[randomimage] and e2 == answerlisty[randomimage]:
             canvas.delete(images)
             randomimage = random.randrange(0,49+1)
             scorecounter = scorecounter + 1
             game = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[randomimage])
             images = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = game, anchor = NW)
        elif pressed == 8 and e1 != answerlistx[randomimage] or e2 !=     answerlisty[randomimage]:
            wronganswer = canvas.create_text(400, 200, text="Incorrect", font="Ubuntu 29 bold", fill=red, anchor=NW)
            e1.delete(0.0,END)   
            e2.delete(0.0,END)
            canvas.after(1500,(canvas.delete(wronganswer)))
```

But I do have it defined in

```
def buttonclick_gamescreen(event):
    global pressed
    pressed = ""

    if event.x >853 and event.x <957 and event.y > 8 and event.y < 56 : pressed = 7 
    if event.x >666 and event.x <947 and event.y > 491 and event.y < 534 : pressed = 8 
    if pressed == 7 :
        window.destroy()
    if pressed == 8:
        print("next button")
```

Which is confusing me.
Could someone please explain me to why this is happening and what I should do to fix it?
Thanks in advance

PS: Basically what I'm trying to do here is when the 'next' button is pressed it will check e1 and e2 and if the string from there matches the answer in the list then it will randomly load another image onto the canvas.

Comment: Format the code, please. Put more attention to indents.

Comment: oh sorry, will do, didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 1):

You don't define the `pressed` in the module level. At least you should do:

```
pressed = ''

def buttonclick_gamescreen(event):
    global pressed
    ...
def gamescreen():
    ...
```

Or you could reorganize your code to a class:

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.pressed = ''
    def gamescreen():
        ...
    ...
```

Or you could use a `StringVar` to trace the value.

Answer (score 1):

Though you have declared the global variable pressed in **def buttonclick_gamescreen(event):** the problem is your **def gamescreen():** is getting called before **def buttonclick_gamescreen(event):**, and hence python runtime cannot lookup a reference named pressed in the memory, since that line of code has never been executed. To demonstrate how this can effect, consider this:

```
def do_something():
    global name
    name = 10
    print name

def do_somehting_else():
    if name == 10:
        print "Valid"
```

Here name is defined global inside the function body. So, when we call:

```
do_something()
do_somehting_else()
```

We get,

```
>>> 10
>>> Valid
```

But, if we change the order of function call to:

```
do_somehting_else()
do_something()
```

The python runtime complains with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/workspace/PyTest/func.py", line 94, in <module>
    do_somehting_else()
  File "/home/rahul/workspace/PyTest/func.py", line 91, in do_somehting_else
    if name == 10:
NameError: global name 'name' is not defined
```

To solve this, if function call is in your control, execute them in a right sequence. If not, create a module level name pressed and access it directly in **def gamescreen():**, the way you did in **def buttonclick_gamescreen(event):**. Basically, like this:

```
global pressed
```

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the definition is not executed before the place where you check `pressed`:

```
def gamescreen():
    # ...
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", buttonclick_gamescreen)  # You only attach callback
    # ...  "pressed" still not defined
    while cdtimer != 0:
        # ...
        if pressed == 8:  # you access "pressed" here
            # ...
```

Either define `pressed` explicitly at the module level, or call `buttonclick_gamescreen` explicitly.

Comment: I am not familiar with tk and it seems `buttonclick_gamescreen` is a event handler. So if the event on button 1 not triggered, you code still will generate an error?

Comment: @zhangyangyu: It is about event-based programming. You first attached event handler, but you did not execute it (because the event did not happen yet). Then you are checking the `passed` variable, which has not been created yet (because it is only created when the event handler is called). Is that clear enough?

Comment: @zhangyangyu: Sorry, I missed you are not OP ;) My answer explains the issue and describes a solution, but does not give code to solve that. Solution is simple: just use first line from your answer.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that. And it seems the code you give is the code with error. I think it is the right one you want to give. Sorry :( @Tadeck

Comment: @zhangyangyu: I am not sure if I am not not clear enough, but I would like to repeat ;) Please read the comments within my code - it explains, why the issue occurred. And yes, the code has the error, because it **is** the code with error - this is why the code says "_You only attach callback_", "_>pressed< still not defined_" and "_you access >pressed< here_" in the comments ;)

Comment: I know your meaning. It's just a misunderstanding. I think you are posting the right code. Actually it is not.@Tadeck